# Indy Server to Server connections

Tags: delphi

My protocol looks like : all clients must go throw the central server 
client connect to central server, ask server for a query, the central server must connect to DbConnector server witch connect to database and execute the query then retur result to the Central server that retur result to the client.

Client : (i need query) -------------------->Cserver

Cserver (execute this query)---------------------DBConnector

DBconnector(return result) ---------------------Cserver

Cserver(return data) ------------------------Client

How the central server, can act as a client to connect to the DBConnector and wait for result,  in the Onexecute event ... 30 to 45 possible client connect at same time.

Comment: Simple: Add a client connection into the server context. It would be easier if we knew exactly which protocol and components you were using.

Comment: @Dagada you have now been given the same answer on *3 different forums*. Is there something you don't understand about CServer needing to use a separate client connection to DBConnector?

Comment: Indy with TCP protocol.  I want to use indy because many people suggest that indy is more pratic than using sock ( winsock). I can done this approche with Beginthread.

Comment: Okay, so are you using `TIdTCPClient` and `TIdTCPServer` then? Indy isn't a component, it's a library of about 50+ components. Also, `WinSock` is the Windows sockets layer. Technically, you're using WinSock whether you like it or not :-)